# Building a search box with taxonomies and custom fields

Tags: search

This is more or less the search form I have in mind by Html, now the problem is transforming all this stuff in php. After the number fields "distance from the sea" (min-max) I'd like to have a meta slider like in this page for the field "rating":https://demo.searchandfilter.com/movies/?_sfm_sfdc_vote_average=0+5 , here is my html:

```
<FORM action="https://sacconicase.com" method="get" target="_self" ><div><label>search by criteria</label><BR></BR><select name="cat" id="cat" > <option value="Category">Category</option></select> </div><div><select name="subcat" id="subcat-1" ><option value="Category">SubCategory</option></select> </div><div><select name="subcat" id="subcat" ><option value="Category">SubSubCategory</option></select> </div><div><div></<label>Facilities</label></div><div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="checbox_value"></input> </div> <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="checbox_value"></input> </div><div><label>number of guests</label><BR></BR><select name="cat" id="cat" > <option value="Category">Taxonomy 1</option></select> </div><BR></BR> <div><label>number of bedrooms</label><BR></BR><select name="cat" id="cat" > <option value="Category">Taxonomy 2</option></select> </div><BR></BR><div><label>Distance from the sea</label><BR></BR><input type="number"</input><span></span>-<input type="number"</input></div><BR></BR><div><button type="button">Search</button></div></form>
```

The results should be posts ordered as the archive pages: https://sacconicase.com/case-vacanza/italia/toscana/marina-di-massa-appartamenti-vacanze/

First 3 selectors are categories/subcategories/sub-subcategories,"Facilities" are tags, then we have taxonomies, custom fields

Comment: There's a few errors in your HTML e.g. `<div></<label>` (incomplete close tag) and `<input type="number"</input>` (missing > from the input open tag)

Comment: Is distance from the sea stored as a meta value? So you're asking how to filter the search on a min or max values for a meta value?

Comment: @Rup yes, distance from the sea: I created a number custom field in my post editor, I'd like to filter also according to this criterium